# setTitleColor not working for custom UIButton in .disabled state

Tags: ios, swift, formatting, uibutton, swiftui-state

I have a form to collect basic user info. There is a "Continue" button on the form that has different appearances based on whether it is in the `.enabled` or `.disabled` state.

The `.enabled` state formatting works fine with the `setTitleColor` method. But when I execute `setTitleColor` for the `.disabled` state, the button text color changes to a different color than the one I want. What is going on?

I have a `CustomButton` subclass of `UIButton` that changes its state to `.disabled` when the text fields above it are empty. Then I call a function to do some custom formatting to give the `.disabled` button a medium grey background with a light grey text.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    // Format a button with filled background
    // Default button text color to white if no parameter is provided
    func configFilledButton(color: UIColor, textColor: UIColor? = UIColor.white) {

        self.titleLabel?.textColor = textColor
        self.backgroundColor = color
        self.setTitleColor(color, for: .disabled)

    } // close configFilledButton


    // Call this function to toggle the Continue button state to disabled
    func toggleEnabledState(isEnabled: Bool) {
    
        if isEnabled == false {
                    
            let newColor = UIColor(named: K.BrandColors.greyMedium)!
            
            self.configFilledButton(
                color: newColor, 
                textColor: UIColor(named: K.BrandColors.greyLight))

     } // close toggleEnabledState 

} // close CustomButton
```

When I run the code to disable the button, the button background changes to the correct color but the title text changes to a color I did not set (I assume it is using some default color for disabled buttons). I verified that the colors I am using in my Assets folder are correctly named and referenced in my constants `K.brandColors` structure.

Any idea why `setTitleColor` does not seem to be working for the `.disabled` state?

Comment: Try replacing `self.titleLabel?.textColor = textColor` with `self.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)`. Probably best not to use two completely different approaches to setting up the colors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I made that change for better consistency but it did not fix the issue with the text color in the .disabled state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save yourself a lot of work by making use of the `.normal` / `.highlighted` / `.disabled` states... and then overriding `isEnabled` to handle the background color change:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    // these will be set by configure()
    private var bkgEnabled: UIColor = .white
    private var bkgDisabled: UIColor = .black

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // configure with defaults
        self.configure()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        // configure with defaults
        self.configure()
    }
    
    // Format a button...
    // Each parameter has a "default" value
    func configure(titleNormal: UIColor? = .white,
                   titleHighlighted: UIColor? = .lightGray,
                   titleDisabled: UIColor? = .darkGray,
                   bkgEnabled: UIColor? = .red,
                   bkgDisabled: UIColor? = .lightGray) {
        
        self.setTitleColor(titleNormal, for: .normal)
        self.setTitleColor(titleHighlighted, for: .highlighted)
        self.setTitleColor(titleDisabled, for: .disabled)
        self.backgroundColor = self.isEnabled ? bkgEnabled : bkgDisabled

        // update background color properties
        self.bkgEnabled = bkgEnabled!
        self.bkgDisabled = bkgDisabled!
    }

    // this will set the background color, based on Enabled / Disabled state
    override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.backgroundColor = isEnabled ? bkgEnabled : bkgDisabled
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here's an example controller... it will create two custom buttons:

- The top button - "button A" - will use the default color values
- we'll set custom color values for the bottom button - "button B"
- tapping the top button will toggle `.isEnabled` state of the bottom button

Controller class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let customButtonA = CustomButton()
    let customButtonB = CustomButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        customButtonA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customButtonB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(customButtonA)
        view.addSubview(customButtonB)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            customButtonA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            customButtonA.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -80.0),

            customButtonB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            customButtonB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customButtonA.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
        ])

        customButtonA.setTitle("Toggle enabled/disabled", for: [])
        customButtonB.setTitle("Enabled", for: [])
        
        customButtonA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnATapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        customButtonB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnBTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        customButtonB.configure(titleNormal: .red, titleHighlighted: .green, titleDisabled: .black, bkgEnabled: .yellow, bkgDisabled: .gray)
        
    }
    @objc func btnATapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Toggling .isEnabled of button B")
        customButtonB.isEnabled.toggle()
        let t: String = customButtonA.isEnabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"
        customButtonB.setTitle(t, for: [])
    }
    @objc func btnBTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Button B tapped")
    }

}

class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    // these will be set by configure()
    private var bkgEnabled: UIColor = .white
    private var bkgDisabled: UIColor = .black

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // configure with defaults
        self.configure()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        // configure with defaults
        self.configure()
    }
    
    // Format a button...
    // Each parameter has a "default" value
    func configure(titleNormal: UIColor? = .white,
                   titleHighlighted: UIColor? = .lightGray,
                   titleDisabled: UIColor? = .darkGray,
                   bkgEnabled: UIColor? = .red,
                   bkgDisabled: UIColor? = .lightGray) {
        
        self.setTitleColor(titleNormal, for: .normal)
        self.setTitleColor(titleHighlighted, for: .highlighted)
        self.setTitleColor(titleDisabled, for: .disabled)
        self.backgroundColor = self.isEnabled ? bkgEnabled : bkgDisabled

        // update background color properties
        self.bkgEnabled = bkgEnabled!
        self.bkgDisabled = bkgDisabled!
    }

    // this will set the background color, based on Enabled / Disabled state
    override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.backgroundColor = isEnabled ? bkgEnabled : bkgDisabled
        }
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this to start:

[image]

while the bottom button is tapped (highlighted):

[image]

and after tapping the top button to disable the bottom button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! This is definitely a better way to organize the function. I changed my code using this as a reference but I am still getting the same issue. 

I created the button using storyboard and set its class to CustomButton inside the Attribute Inspector. Could some storyboard attribute be overwriting or superseding the titleColor we set programmatically?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I am now noticing that the background color also does not seem to be affected by anything I set programmatically. It seems likely that something is going on with how I set it up in storyboard

Comment: In Storyboard, are you changing the button **Style** from **Plain** to **Default**? If not, do so.

Answer (score 0):

`self.setTitleColor(color, for: .disabled)` is wrong. Please use `self.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .disabled)`

> When the button enters the disabled state, an alpha value is applied to both the text and background. If you want the text color to remain solid without alpha, set the text color using the `.disabled` state. Otherwise, use the `.normal` state for text color.

Comment: Thank you, good catch! I was using the wrong color variable and fixed the error. However it did not fix issue with the text color in the .disabled state

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't find a solution to this, I had the same issue and solved it by using an attributedTitle for the buttons, changing the foregroundColor attribute based on enabled state.

You wouldn't need to subclass UIButton, but if you do, your configure function could look something like this:

```
func configure(title: String?,
               titleColorNormal: UIColor? = .white,
               titleColorDisabled: UIColor? = .darkGray) {

    if let title {
        let attNormal = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title,
                                                  attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColorNormal!])
        self.setAttributedTitle(attNormal, for: .normal)
        
        let attDisabled = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title,
                                                  attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColorDisabled!])
        self.setAttributedTitle(attDisabled, for: .disabled)
    }
}
```

You could add other attributes, e.g. font, in the attributedTitle.